# How to draw Logic gates like the following :

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, circuitikz, logic, circuits

I would like to draw the following logic gates. Actually I'm new in latex, so I have no idea how to draw it in latex.  I can Draw this in Adobe photoshop, but I know latex produces better image quality. So I want to draw it in latex.
[image]

**Added :**   I have tried with the following code, but I can not add the remaining gates. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  circuits.logic,
  circuits.logic.US
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
  \node[not gate] (n) {};
  \draw (n.input) -- +(-.1,0);
  \draw (n.output) -- +(.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You may find some inspirations in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32863/164314).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you can do it in Adobe Photoshop, the simplest solution would be to output a .eps file which you can then include in your TeX file with `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 2):

More o less:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  circuits.logic,
  circuits.logic.US,
  positioning
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US,
    node distance=8mm]
    \node[and gate] (and1) {};
    \draw (and1.input 1)--++(180:3cm) node[left] (y) {y};
    \draw (and1.input 2)--++(180:3cm) node[left] (z) {z};
    \node[and gate, below =of and1] (and2) {};
    \node[and gate, below =of and2] (and3) {};
    \node[not gate, left=5mm of and2.input 1, scale=.5] (not1) {};
    \node[not gate, left=5mm of and3.input 2, scale=.5] (not2) {};
    \draw (not1)--(and2.input 1);
    \draw (not2)--(and3.input 2);
    \draw (not1.input)--++(180:5mm) coordinate (aux) |- (y);
    \draw (aux) |- (and3.input 1);
    \draw (not2.input)--++(180:10mm) coordinate (aux) |- (z);
    \draw (aux) |- (and2.input 2);

    \node[or gate, right=of and2, anchor=input 1] (or1) {};
    \draw (and2)--(or1.input 1);
    \draw (and3)-|([xshift=-5mm]or1.input 2)--(or1.input 2);

    \node[and gate, right= of or1, anchor=input 1] (and4) {};
    \draw (or1.output)--(and4.input 1);
    \draw (and4.input 2)--++(180:5mm) |- ([yshift=-3mm]and3.south) coordinate (aux) -- (aux-|y.east) node[left] (x) {x};

    \node[or gate, right= of and4, anchor=input 2] (or2) {};
    \draw (and4)-|([xshift=-5mm]or2.input 2)--(or2.input 2);
    \draw (and1)-|([xshift=-5mm]or2.input 1)--(or2.input 1);
    \draw (or2.output)--++(0:1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A more complete option and experiment with edges to draw each arrow, this code is derived from my answer in [How to draw logic gates in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449056/154390)

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.gates.logic.US,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment config
        font=\LARGE,
        thick,
        >={Stealth[length=12pt]},
        %Environment styles
        GateCfg/.style={
            logic gate inputs={normal,normal,normal},
            draw,
            scale=2,
            on grid % Distances from shape centers
        }
    ]
    \path % Place gate shapes using positioning commands
        node[and gate US,GateCfg](AND1){} 
        node[and gate US,GateCfg,below=3 of AND1](AND2){}
        node[and gate US,GateCfg,below=3 of AND2](AND3){} 
        node[or gate US,GateCfg, below right= 1.5 and 5 of AND2](OR1){}
        node[and gate US,GateCfg, below right= 0.5 and 5 of OR1](AND4){}
        node[or gate US,GateCfg, above right= 1 and 5 of AND4](OR2){}
        node[not gate US, draw,left=1 of AND2.input 1](N1){}
        node[not gate US, draw,left=1.5 of AND3.input 3](N2){};

    \draw % Coordinate "temp" is redefined in each coordinate (temp) instruction 
        (OR2.output) 
            edge[->] ++(3,0)
        (AND4.output) 
            -- ++(1,0) coordinate (temp) |- (OR2.input 3) edge[<-]++(-10pt,0)
        (AND1.output)
            -- (AND1-| temp) |- (OR2.input 1) edge[<-]++(-10pt,0)
        (OR1.output) 
            edge[->] (OR1 -| AND4.input 1)
        (AND2.output)
            -- ++(2,0) coordinate(temp) |- (OR1.input 1) edge[<-]++(-10pt,0)
        (AND3.output)
            -- (AND3-| temp) |- (OR1.input 3) edge[<-]++(-10pt,0)
        (AND1.input 1)
            edge[<-]++(-10pt,0) 
            -- ++(-4,0) coordinate (init) node[anchor=east]{y}
            node[pos=0.6](temp){}
        (AND1.input 3 -| temp)
            ++(0,5pt) edge (temp.center)
            arc (90:-90:5pt) |- (N1.input) edge[<-]++(-10pt,0)
        (AND2.input 3 -| temp)
            ++(0,5pt) edge (AND2.input 1 -| temp)
            arc (90:-90:5pt) |- (AND3.input 1) edge[<-]++(-10pt,0)
        (AND1.input 3)
            edge[<-]++(-10pt,0) 
            -- ++(-4,0) coordinate (init) node[anchor=east]{z}
            node[pos=0.8](temp){}
        (AND2.input 3 -| temp)
            edge (temp.center)
            edge[->] (AND2.input 3)
        (N2.input -| temp)
            edge (AND2.input 3 -| temp)
            edge[->] (N2.input)
        (AND2.input 1)
            edge[<-] (N1)
        (AND3.input 3)
            edge[<-] (N2)
        (init)++(0,-7) node[anchor=east]{x} 
            -- ++(12,0) coordinate (temp)
            -- (AND4.input 3 -| temp)
            edge[->] (AND4.input 3);

    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

**Why tikz picture environment in standalone document class?**

It allows you to import the pdf output from the tikz standalone class using graphicx package, without loosing svg or vector properties, within figure environment in the main document scaled by the value \textwidth in:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tikz_drawing_in_standalone_class_pdf_output.pdf}
```